# How to troubleshoot when the HCL OneTest Data pod container goes down?

Tags: docker, containers

When the HCL OneTest Data pod container goes down, is there any way to troubleshoot and bring the pods up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands to manage and troubleshoot the HCL OneTest Data pods:

https://help.hcltechsw.com/onetest/hclonetestserver/10.1.2/com.hcl.test.otd.help.doc/topics/r_help_commands_for_logs.html